# Security through virtualization: does Ryzen support Rapid Virtualization Indexing (RVI), aka Second Level Address Translation (SLAT)?

Tags: virtualization, qubes-os

RVI is required by Windows Hyper-V...
RVI will be required by QubeOS 4...

Lots of info about the new RYZEN CPU Series but as far as I know, no news about RVI support ? So, any source to point at about this ?

[EDIT] my question is only about RVI

Comment: I can't find anything that outright says that it supports RVI/SLAT, but it will support the following instruction set features/extensions: AMD-V (Compute Virtualization) • VT-d/Vi (I/O MMU Virtualization)

Comment: yeah, thanx but that's what I already know... * sigh *
AMD stil don't even have an official full datasheet ;(

Comment: wow, someone is keen on preordering stuff.

Comment: Though these techniques have security applications, this question is not about information security at all.

Comment: JOW : I won't preorder, I'll let first buyers/testers answer :)
Marcüs Müller : Let's all agree that RVI can be considered as a security feature when you are looking for secure hardware for secure OS for secure info... :)